# Is it good practice to have most of your code under one key frame in action script 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I was just wondering because in my project a majority of my code is in one key frame (albeit contained within a variety of movieclips). It seems counter intuitive to do it any other way but it still just doesn't feel organized enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how i like to do it so i only have the comb thru one frame of script. and it also renders all the script to make sure your AS is running before the required movie clips are on stage.

I havent had any problems stacking my AS into one frame.
But that's just me.

There may be a more practical answer out there..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you can, I'd recommend you to try to move to AS3. AS3 is more solid than AS2 and will let you organize your code in a more clean and efficient way.

That being said, although I preferred to separate code into classes in AS2, [Adobe Best Practices for AS2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/as_bestpractices.html) states:

**Keeping Your ActionScript Code in One Place**

> Whenever possible, put your ActionScript 2.0 code in a single location, such as in one or more external ActionScript files or on Frame 1 of the Timeline (when placed on the timeline, the code is called a frame script).

**Attaching Code to Objects**

> You must avoid attaching ActionScript code to objects (such as button or movie clip instances) in a FLA file, even in simple or prototype applications.

You can find the detailed reasons and more coding practices for AS2 in that document.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine for small projects, but once you get into larger projects, you'll find more and more bugs creep into your code.

You'll really want to research object-oriented programming if you want to do solid flash development.

Have you ever used classes or done any sort of OOP? This is a little too open-ended of a question, but I recommend doing some research.

Here is a decent tutorial in reference to AS2:
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/oop2/AS2OOPindex.htm